# Load multiple csv files in different tables using sql loader at once

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Just started playing around with sql loader.
I have multiple csv files which I want to load into respective tables.
I used sql loader and created multiple .ctl files one for each csv and I was able to run them one at a time to upload the data to my tables.
But instead of running multiple commands, I want to create a script that will run all these commands at once. Is there a way to do this in a shell script?
Edit: I will be using Linux Rh7
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not ... `sqlldr` is an operating system executable so you can call it from a batch / shell script. The way it looks depends on operating system you use (and you didn't mention).

Comment: Thank you. I will be using Linux Red Hat 7. Just updated my question

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know Unix so I can't write any code for you, sorry.